# Using an Array to get the average of a selection of numbers

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have 12 different numbers on a row in an excel sheet (repeated few times on different row) and I would like to get the average of the 8 bigger numbers (4 numbers won't be used). I thought to use an array, but how to select the 8 bigger numbers in this array?

I would like to do it in VBA. Do you have any ideas/directions how to proceed, because I am not really sure how to start.

Example: `12,3,5,6,8,11,9,7,5,8,10,1 (Results=8.875)`, if I didn't make a mistake!
Thanks.

Comment: In VBA it is easy - are you sure a formula won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you asked for VBA, but here's a formula. If this works, you can quickly throw in VBA (use the macro recorder to see how if you're unsure).

If that's in row 1, you can use:

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:L1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}))
```

You should be able to change `A1:l1` to be the range where your numbers are, i.e.

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:F2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}))
```

Edit: Per your comment, also no need for VBA. Just use conditional highlighting.   Highlight your range of numbers, then go to Conditional Highlighting --> Top/Bottom Rules --> Top 10 Items.  Then just change the `10` to `8`, and choose a color/format. Then Apply!

[image]

(each row in the above is treated as it's own range).

Edt2: bah, my image has duplicate numbers which is why the top 8 rule is highlighting 9 numbers sometimes. If you request I'll try  to edit and tweak

Comment: Thanks, it's work very well with this Formula. I didn't know this one. I was actually thinking VBA, because I wanted to highlight the selected cells in green as well.

Comment: @JLuc01 - Ah okay, still you could do that without VBA. See my edit, I think that would do the trick.

Comment: Great! I think I am thinking too much VBA because I don't know enough the power of excel.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple Excel function to compute the answer

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:L1, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}))
```

It is a bit more complex in VBA, but here is a function that does the same computation (explicit typing per Mat's Mug):

```
Public Function AvgTop8(r As Range) As Double
    Dim Sum As Double, j1 As Integer
    For j1 = 1 To 12
        If WorksheetFunction.Rank(r(1, j1), r) <= 8 Then
            Sum = Sum + r(1, j1)
        End If
    Next j1
    AvgTop8 = Sum / 8#
End Function
```

The Excel RANK function returns the rank of a number in a list of numbers, with the largest rank 1 and so on. So you can search through the 12 numbers for the 8 largest, sum them and divide by 8.

Comment: What's the `#` for in `Sum = 0#`?

Comment: @BruceWayne it's a type hint, making `0` a `Double` literal, and thus `Sum` an implicit `Variant/Double`. Better do `Dim Sum As Double` and explicitly declare all the variables.

Comment: @BruceWayne @MatsMug Excel did that itself when I typed in `Sum = 0.0`... and I like type inference.

Comment: The problem is that VBA (the *VBE* did that, Excel/the host app has nothing to do with it!) doesn't really do type inference (other than this "convenient" literal typing "autocorrect"): undeclared variables are simply `Variant`, and these can hold literally *anything* - at the cost of run-time & storage overhead. It's more like *duck-typing*: member calls on `Variant/Object` are always late-bound (validated/resolved at run-time).

Comment: @Mat'sMug I like Duck Typing too - LOL. What happens to the 8 in the last line of the function, even if I declare Sum as Double ?

Comment: `AvgTop8` has no declared return type, so that's a `Variant` - then `Sum` is `Variant/Double`, and `8` is an `Integer` literal, so the RHS expression must resolve to `Variant/Double`, making the LHS that as well, so the function returns a `Variant/Double`. The `8` remains an `Integer` all along =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Fixed the return type. Presumably the 8 `Integer` would be converted to a `Double` by the division operator at some point?

Comment: I'd have to dig up the specs to confirm, but IIRC expression evaluation involving compatible types only converts the *result* of the expression to the LHS type (that's when a *type mismatch* error can occur). From a quick test in the *immediate pane* it doesn't appear that expression evaluation has side-effects on the operands themselves (tested with a `String` operand too, seems implicit conversion is made in-place).. and the expression always resolves to the widest type involved.

Comment: I wouldn't expect side effects on the operands, but I did wonder about `8` versus `8#`, but since / has a `Double` result, presumably it coerces its operands to be `Double` regardless.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need VBA for this. You can use:

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:L1,{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8}))
```